# Why child overflows parent's left padding in FF when parent is button?

Tags: css, firefox

When button's children overflows button itself, they normally do it to the right, but in FF they suddenly do it the the left. How can I prevent such a behaviour? Is it FF bug?

Sample HTML:

```
<button class="test"><span class="child"></span><span class="child"></span></button>
```

Sample CSS:

```
.test {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: blue;
}
```

Example: http://cssdeck.com/labs/m6vnniol

Comment: Because you have `white-space:nowrap` on the parent see http://jsfiddle.net/XXesZ/ it overflows the bottom because there is not enough horizontal space to fit both boxes

Comment: The question was why it overflows to the left(!), not to the right.

Comment: I already know, that I can use child's margin instead of parent's padding, but I want exactly parent's padding, cause in that case I can use advantages of parent's content-box sizing.

Comment: You would have to investigate the button element for FF, it does not behave the same as a div. My guess is its default is probably inline-block. Box-sizing really has no effect on the button in FF, because the box looks the same with it and without it